# Group by category in pandas DataFrame object output to dictionary object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame object that looks something like the following:

```
    In [106]: df
    Out [106]: df[
                     Amount       Category         
          date
    2014-08-05        18.40        Thing01  
    2014-08-05       192.60        Thing01
    2014-08-05        10.42        Thing02
    2014-08-05        13.34        Thing07
    2014-08-05       364.56        Thing04
    2014-08-05       843.21        Thing03
    2014-08-04        14.65        Thing04
    2014-08-04        56.98        Thing11
    2014-08-04        76.21        Thing99
    2014-08-04       786.22        Thing99
    2014-08-04        87.44        Thing99
    2014-08-04        53.23        Thing01
    2014-08-04        32.12        Thing99
    ]
```

I want to group this data by "Category" and use the result to create a Python dictionary that looks something like this:

```
In [107]: OutInfo
Out [107]: OutInfo = {

     Thing01:
                           Amount
                date             
          2014-08-05        18.40
          2014-08-05       192.60
          2014-08-04        53.23

     Thing02:
                           Amount
                date    
          2014-08-05        10.42

     Thing07:
                           Amount
                date
          2014-08-05        13.34

     Thing04:
                           Amount
                date
          2014-08-05       364.56
          2014-08-04        14.65

     Thing03:
                           Amount
                date
          2014-08-05       843.21

     Thing11:
                           Amount
                date
          2014-08-04        56.98

     Thing99:
                           Amount
                date
          2014-08-04        76.21
          2014-08-04       786.22
          2014-08-04        87.44
 }
```

I have tried using commands like: df.groupby("Category") with various functions at the end including the .apply method (which I don't fully understand either...).  I tried other methods, but the fact that I have multiple entries for one day prevented me from using those.  Thanks in advance for any help!

-Jeremy

Comment: I am trying to avoid using loops.  I already have a solution that uses "for" loops, but that is SLOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is the right idea. To get exactly what you want, you could do something like

```
>>> d = {k: v.drop("Category", axis=1) for k,v in list(df.groupby("Category"))}
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'Thing01':             Amount
date              
2014-08-05   18.40
2014-08-05  192.60
2014-08-04   53.23,
[...]
 'Thing99':             Amount
date              
2014-08-04   76.21
2014-08-04  786.22
2014-08-04   87.44
2014-08-04   32.12}
```

If you call `list` on a `groupby` object, you get a list of group key/value tuples.  If you call `dict(list(grouped))`, this becomes a dictionary.  Ordinarily, though, you don't remove the key column as in your example desired output.  So if you're willing to keep the extra column around, it's even easier:

```
>>> d = dict(list(df.groupby("Category")))
>>> d["Thing01"]
            Amount Category
date                       
2014-08-05   18.40  Thing01
2014-08-05  192.60  Thing01
2014-08-04   53.23  Thing01
```

Comment: There is no need to convert to list. Just iterate over the groupby object `d = {k: v.drop("Category", axis=1) for k,v in df.groupby("Category")}`

Comment: I went with the dict(list(df.groupby("Category"))) approach. It shaved a full second off the "for" loop I had been using. Thanks!